# How to Access Props in React Functional Component Using Props.Match.Params

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

Props seems to be passed successfully from parent component to child component based on the log, but I'm getting a typeerror undefined message when attempting to pull a picture for display from a specific property.

**Parent.js**

```
...
const [myState, setMyState] = useState([]);

useEffect( () => {
  axios
  .get('/gogetit')
  .then(res => {
    setMyState(res.data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
}, []);

...

<BrowserRouter>
...
  <Route path="/child/:id" exact 
    render={(routerProps) => (
      <Child {...routerProps} 
        myState={myState}
      />
    )} 
  />
...
```

**Child.js**

```
const Child = (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.myState); //ok [ {id: '1', src:'url'}, {id: '2', src:'url2'} ]
    console.log(props.match.params.id); //ok 0
    console.log(props.myState[props.match.params.id]); //ok {id: '1', src:'url'}
    console.log(props.myState[props.match.params.id].src); //not ok undefined
  })

  return
  ...
    <img src={props.blurbs[props.match.params.id].src} />
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `myState` state array is initially empty, so from the initial render cycle to whenever the GET request resolves and populates the `myState` array, `myState[any index]` will be undefined and attempting to access a property of undefined will throw an error.

Use a guard-clause/null-check

```
console.log(
  props.myState &&
  props.myState[props.match.params.id] && 
  props.myState[props.match.params.id].src
);
```

or Optional Chaining operator

```
console.log(props.myState?.[props.match.params.id]?.src);
```

The idea here is that each property access of any potentially null/undefined object is checked to be truthy prior to accessing into it.

...

```
<img src={props.blurbs?.[props.match.params.id]?.src} />
```

Comment: Thank you; for me, optionalChaining did not work out of the box due to 'Support for the experimental syntax 'optionalChaining' isn't currently enabled'; to bypass this message, i had to delete the node_modules folder and webpack and webpack-dev-server lines in the package.json file, then run 'npm install' in the frontend root folder